# Inheritance of css in li, ul and ol. Explanation or reference needed

Tags: html, css

I was drafting a quick test of how styling works in nested lists in HTML and CSS. I was trying to showcase how the child selector works in difference to the general decendant selector (don't know if that's the correct term) ul li, vs ul > li.

But when I put color red on ul > li, then ONLY the child li in the ul SHOULD get red colored text, but turns out that all text in ul inherits that color. Could someone be so kind and explain to me why this happens with only text properties, for example color, text-align and text-decoration. While properties like background-color and border doesn't get passed down to the grandchildren (as it correctly should work with > selector). Or just send me a link to somewhere where this is explained!

Thanks in advance!

```css
ul {
  background-color: red;
}

ul li {
  background-color: green;
}

ul>li {
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

ul>li>ol {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Test</title>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
      Unsorted List
      <li>
        First Items In Unordered List
        <ol>
          First Ordered List
          <li>First Ordered Item</li>
          <li>Second Ordered Item</li>
          <li>Third Ordered Item</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        Second Item In Unordered List
        <ol>
          Second Ordered List
          <li>First Ordered Item</li>
          <li>Second Ordered Item</li>
          <li>Third Ordered Item</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        Third Item In Unordered List
        <ol>
          Third Ordered List
          <li>First Ordered Item</li>
          <li>Second Ordered Item</li>
          <li>Third Ordered Item</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: All text _is_ within `ul > li` elements.

Comment: No, all text is within ul li, but not within ul > li. All children beyond the first li should be ignored, but since some properties have inherit as standard, they get it anyway.

Comment: Which text isn't contained within the start and end tags of a `ul > li` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's divide your question into 2 parts,

1. what exactly `ul > li` means?

For CSS `color` property, it doesn't mean the first children of `ul` only, it also means some elements & their properties inside the children unless you set different `color` for them, for example-

```html
<style>
  ul > li {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<ul>
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li> MY ROOMS
    <ul>
      <li>BED ROOM</li>
      <li>KITCHEN</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>GARDEN</li>
</ul>
```

The `color: red;` is applied not only to `ul > li` but also to `ul > li > ul > li`. Now, if you set a different color for them, then they will not inherit the `color` from `ul > li` anymore, see the example below-

```html
<style>
ul > li {
color: red;
}
  ul > li li {
    color: green;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
  }
</style>

<ul>
  <li>HOME</li>
  <li> MY ROOMS
    <ul>
      <li>BED ROOM</li>
      <li>KITCHEN</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>GARDEN</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see the child list items color is different now. You can also see the `border` around them and their color, here comes the second part of your question-

2. Is CSS `color` property applicable to text only?

The answer is **NO**, if CSS `color` property is applied to an element, it means it's also applied to the following properties of following children of **that element**-

- The text color of the value of `alt` attribute (of `img` tag which is a child of **that element**)
- The `border-color` of `ul`, `ol`  &  `li` (which are children of **that element**)
- The `list-style-type` color of `li` (which is a child of **that element**)

Now, see the example below-

```html
<style>
  div {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;

    /* color */
    color: green
  }

  ol li,
  ul {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
  }
</style>

<div>
  <img src="01.jpg" alt="This is a missing img tag">
  <br>
  <br>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  <ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

I have learned this from some tutorial I forgot but after some googling I found [an article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/color/#usage-notes) that could be more useful for you, and [this is a w3school page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trysel.asp) you can learn more about CSS selectors from here, good luck.

Comment: "It doesn't mean the first child of ul only" — No, it means *every* child but none of their children. The fact that a grandchild might have `inherit` which causes it to copy the value from the parent doesn't mean that that combinator is a descendant combinator.

Comment: I changed that part, "It doesn't mean the first child of ul only" it was meant for `color` property only, I changed it, please lemme know what you think now. Thank you so much for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

Properties are inherited when they have the value `inherit`.

The default stylesheets provided by browsers have `inherit` as the default value for properties where it would generally be considered useful.

It is useful that given:

```
<p style="color: blue">The quick <em>brown</em> fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
```

… the `em` element inherits the colour instead of forcing you to respecify it.

It **isn't** useful for a background to be inherited because that would layer over the top of the previous one. A background image would restart on the `em` element while a translucent background colour would multiply the opacity of its parent.

Comment: I agree with your answer but it would be hard to confirm without any official documentation. can you share any referenced document for the above explanation?

Comment: I'm not aware of anywhere that a browser vendor has documented their thought processes for the design of their default stylesheet.

Comment: So this behavior could differ from browser to browser?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border = inherit "no". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color has inherit "yes"